# Python - error when executing script

Tags: python

I am trying to execute [this script](https://medium.com/@rahulrrixe/secedgar-crawler-3c28e53204fe):

```
import time
from SECEdgar.crawler import SecCrawler

def get_filings():
    t1 = time.time()

    # create object
    seccrawler = SecCrawler()

    companyCode = 'AAPL'    # company code for apple 
    cik = '0000320193'      # cik code for apple
    date = '20010101'       # date from which filings should be downloaded
    count = '10'            # no of filings

    seccrawler.filing_10Q(str(companyCode), str(cik), str(date), str(count))
    seccrawler.filing_10K(str(companyCode), str(cik), str(date), str(count))
    seccrawler.filing_8K(str(companyCode), str(cik), str(date), str(count))
    seccrawler.filing_13F(str(companyCode), str(cik), str(date), str(count))

    t2 = time.time()
    print "Total Time taken: ",
    print (t2-t1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_filings()
```

I am putting this code in a file filings.py , then attempt to run it from terminal (Mac user)

```
python filings.py
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filings.py", line 2, in <module>
    from SECEdgar.crawler import SecCrawler
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/SECEdgar/crawler.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/SECEdgar/config.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/configparser.py", line 995, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Paths'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you followed the proper steps of installation of the SEC-Edgar as mentioned in the site?

Comment: Check your [SECEdgar/default.cfg](https://github.com/rahulrrixe/SEC-Edgar/blob/master/SECEdgar/default.cfg) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was basically a quite silly thing:

```
date = '20010101'       # date from which filings should be downloaded
```

should be

```
date = '20010101'       # date UNTIL which filings should be downloaded
```

so if you put the starting date you would end up with download 0 files, but if you put the end date then you would download them all successfully, seems to be working OK now :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's an error in the package you installed. 
Try uninstalling and reinstalling.

```
pip uninstall SECEdgar

pip install SECEdgar
```